# Is there any Typo3-, MagentoChangelog as RSS Feed?

Tags: magento, rss, typo3, feed, changelog

See Title.
I can't find anything like that =/
The only possible way i see, is to parse it from the websites via php but I assume that this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All TYPO3 CMS changes as RSS Feed: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commits/master.atom

Each released version also has release notes, which are located in the wiki: http://wiki.typo3.org/Category:ReleaseNotes/TYPO3_7.x
The releases notes contain some additional information next to the list of changes (like warnings fpr breaking changes, tips how to upgrade things safely etc)

Magento moved to GitHub recently, so you have a Feed of all changes as well: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commits/develop.atom